# Visual Studio is checking out the C++ vcxproj and vcxproj.filters files even there are no changes made

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, nuget

My solution consists of several managed and unmanaged libraries. I am using NuGet for all projects (even for the unmanaged libraries). I am not storing the packages in source control (I am using the option "Enable NuGet package restore"). Since introducing this change with NuGet, the unmanaged projects files (vcxproj and vcxproj.filter) are checked out by VS even there were no changes made. Does anybody has a clue what could be the issue?. I think it is connected with NuGet.